# Check if date-format is in 2013-11-29 or 29-11-2013 format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have this statement:

```
@termine = @current_department.termins.where(date: Date.strptime(params[:date], '%d-%m-%Y')).to_json
```

I convert the date `29-11-2013` to `2013-11-29`:

```
Date.strptime(params[:date], '%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Then I tried to pass `2013-11-29` as `params[:date]`, but I got the error:

```
invalid date
```

How can I check to see in which format the date is?

Comment: Where do the date values come from? Users given the chance to enter them by hand will mess you up, sometimes on purpose. Don't let them choose the format, use a date-picker pop up or some select/option lists to force the format consistency. It's part of giving them a good UI experience and providing you known good data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `begin .. rescue ..`:

```
date_str = '2013-11-29'
begin
  d = Date.strptime(date_str, '%d-%m-%Y')
rescue ArgumentError
  d = Date.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
end
d # => #<Date: 2013-11-29 ((2456626j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not going to be processing years before 100 AD, you can simply check to see if both the second and third characters of the string are numeric.

That will be enough to distinguish those two formats. You have to check both second and third characters in case the day may be a single digit but, if they're both numeric (not a `-`), it has to be the `YYYY-*` variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expression patterns.

`(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})` will give you YYYY-MM-DD

`(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})` will give you DD-MM-YYYY

EDIT: should be noted that this will capture DD and MM regardless of order so you'll want to validate the groups are > or < 12.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently trying to match your database's date format. You don't need to.

Take out the `strptime` and just throw the date, in any format, at Rails, and `Time.parse` will internally figure it out.